# Finding the expected value of a quadratic transformation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am given that X is a random variable with a mean of two and variance of 4, as per the question:

[image]

So, I try to solve the problem by expanding $E[x+2]^2$

$$E[x+2]^2 = E[x+2] * E[x+2]$$
$$E[x+2] = E[x] + E[2] = 2 + 2 = 4$$
$$E[x+2]^2 = 4*4=16$$

However, the answer is 16. I think I am missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Does anyone know why?

Comment: The notation is a little ambiguous. You are asked to find $E[(X+2)^2]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$E(X+2)^2=E(X^2+4X+4)=E(X^2)+4E(X)+4$$ and $E(X^2)=Var(X)+(E(X))^2=4+2^2=8$
so the answer is 20.

In statistical calculation,usually,  when we write $E(X+2)^2$ we means $E\bigg((X+2)^2\bigg)$ and $E^2(X+2)=\bigg(E(X+2)\bigg)^2$